# How can I revisit Rift Planes?

Tags: gravity-rush

Rift Planes are the weird other dimensional places where you bright back Perry's of the city together. This far I've only reached these by way of story missions and there's no clear way to return.

Some trophies require me to do things in the rift; can I return to the rift? If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talk to Gade outside of Kat's house. You need to have finished Chapter 17 before you can return to the rift planes.

Comment: also, if you revisit them after you beat the game, there will be some ... challenging enemies

Comment: @Spartacus the unique nevi or something else? The unique nevi are always there I think, just hidden

Comment: @BenBrocka I thought that those don't spawn until after you beat the game, maybe I just missed them the first time through then